# Wrapped context doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var parent = $('<div>parent</div>');
$('div').wrap(parent);

parent.append('<div>appended</div>');
```

I am testing it with below html code and append method doesn't work  on parent object. Where i am doing mistake ?

```
<div>child</div>
```

Edit: Expected html result is

```
<div>parent
<div>child</div>
<div>appended</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What should be the result? Adding something afterwards to `parent` won't have any effect on the elements that have been used for wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('div').wrap('<div>parent</div>').after('<div>appended</div>');
```

As every `div` is the only child of the wrapped around element, appending to the parent is the same as inserting the new element after the `div`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/GNHz4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $(parent).html($(parent).html() + '<div>appended</div>');
```

Or

```
 $(parent).append($('<div></div>').html('appended'));
```

Also this might work

```
 $(parent).append($('<div>appended</div>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You caould try giving the child and ID:

**HTML**

```
<div id="child">child</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var parent = '<div>parent</div>';
$('div').wrap(parent);

$('#child').parent().append('<div>appended</div>');
```

This works a treat, check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/MXbMQ/

Comment: There is no reason to give the element an ID. `$('div').parent()...` would work as well.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Not true, edit my fiddle above, and see the result. It will append two `<div>appended</div>`

Comment: True. Because now it also selects the "parent" div. Anyway, this could be solved with method chaining: `$('div').wrap(parent).parent().append('<div>appended</div>');`.